# Facebook : Post in user wall without SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I use below code to post in user wall ,without SDK, it posts successfully , but its not returning the post id , please help me

```
<?php
$token=$_GET['token'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$msg = "wooow thats soo possible";
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/feed";
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => $token,
'message' => $msg);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $result;

?>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use php sdk?

Comment: I am using some kinda server where i cant upload all files,!! so please help me with curl.

Comment: and how will you upload this file?

Comment: vi test.php , then just paste this code in ssh :P

Comment: if you have ssh access - then you can upload anything. Read about scp

Comment: yea ok i will try :) but can some one explain why it is not returning post id , my head is blowing lol :D

Comment: the thing is - it's **much easier** to use their SDK, rather than reinvent the wheel, especially when you cannot debug trivial 10 lines script. So I would better read about scp and upload FB PHP SDK there

Answer (score 0):

I got solution , below code works

```
 <?php
$token=$_GET['token'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/feed";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $token,                        
                        'message'          => "cool winne"
                    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result= curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

?>
```